# How to resolve Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0202009 in SSIS

Tags: database, ssis, db2

I have an SSIS package that consists of data flow tasks and contains an OLEDB source from DB2 and OLDB Target. The provider is microsoft oledb for db2..This used to run fine, but now I've got an error as shown below.

> Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0202009
> Error atxx [OLE DB Source [478]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.
> An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E14.
> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft DB2 OLE DB Provider"
> Hresult: 0x80040E14  Description: ""DATAWAREHOUSEUSRچBIN"
> does not have the privilege to perform operation "".".

Comment: This looks to be a permissions error based on the message: `does not have the privilege to perform operation`. Are you calling a procedure, could you test the login's permissions separately from the SSIS package?

Comment: Ask the Db2 DBA for information about any changes to the permissions, authorisations and group-memberships of the account (or roles) being used by SSIS when connecting to Db2, and additionally for any change information for security of the related packages in Db2 that SSIS uses.  Either some user or group related change happened, or some database change happened with the security of the  packages, tables/views, routines, or authorisation/privileges of users/groups/roles.  This is not a programming question, it is simple database administation.